# Post/Pre build macro throwing error in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio

I have the following macro in post build event:

```
copy   "$(SolutionDir)\HelloTest.txt"  "$(OutDir)"
```

When I run the build I am getting following error.

```
Error   3   The command "copy   "E:\VS2012Projects\MixTests\\HelloTest.txt"  "bin\Debug\"" exited with code 1.  MixTests
```

What am I missing here ?

Comment: There's a superfluous backslash in the path. Also, the error is the result of the operation(s) you perform in the build event, so run the same commands in the command line to maybe get more verbose messages. This is a path issue, though. Also, use `xcopy`.

Comment: try removing the backslash after `solutionDir`: `copy   "$(SolutionDir)HelloTest.txt"  "$(OutDir)"`

Comment: @w0lf Even after removing the \, it has same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try defining your post-build event like this:

```
copy "$(SolutionDir)HelloTest.txt" "$(ProjectDir)$(OutDir)"
```

I suspect the problem is related to the fact that `(OutDir)` is (probably) `bin\Debug` and it is not applied relatively to the project's root.

Using `$(ProjectDir)$(OutDir)` will put the absolute path to your project's `...\bin\Debug` folder, removing any uncertainty.

Answer (score 0):

An old thread, but someone might find this useful.

If you have spaces in the folder names that contain your solution, this seems to cause issues. For example;

"C:\Projects\ABC Project\my.sln" - corresponds to a $(SolutionDir) with NO trailing slash
where as
"C:\Projects\ABCProject\my.sln" - corresponds to a $(SolutionDir) with a trailing slash

A common issue when keeping two branches side by side as local copies. Be careful with the folder naming. I.e.
"C:\Projects\ABCProject\my.sln" - trunk
"C:\Projects\ABCProject 1_0\my.sln" - branch

Is likely to cause issues in the local branch copy.